# Giving values to the tooltip from xml file in odoo 9

Tags: xml, odoo, nvd3.js

I am using `nvd3.js` to create graph view in odoo 9  in that how can i give values to the tooltip from my xml file, it taking both x and y axis values but i have to give new values to the tooltip

[image]

Comment: Question is not clear, can you elaborate it?

Comment: hi vignesh in my graph view tooltip displaying the  x and y axis value, but i have to add new  values to the tooltip and i  have added a image in the question please see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Navigate to the file in the path
addons/web/static/lib/nvd3/nv.d3.js

2) Search the text in it 'nv.models.multiBarChart = function()'

3) `tooltip = function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
        return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
               '<p>' +  y + ' on ' + x + '</p>'
      }`

The above code is responsible for displaying the tool tip

4) So add the frequency value like

```
`tooltip = function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<h3>' + 'hello world' + '</h3>' +
           '<p>' +  y + ' on ' + x + '</p>'
  }`
```

[Demo](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/601c66edfb83a11cf2bb)

Comment: thank you vignesh you are great, and such a amazing person

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4142382/j-v-manoj-kumar the above answer works correctly or not, If it is then mark the answer

Comment: vignesh how can i send values from  the xml file

Comment: <graph string="hello world" type="bar">
                 <field name="id" type="column"/>
                 <field name="percent" type="measure"/> 
              </graph>                                                                                                                   in this i have to send the tooltip values too

Comment: Tooltip value depend upon the key value

Comment: hi vignesh tell me how to inherit the java script file